# checkout_cart_update_items_before magento 2 not able to get product in this event

Tags: magento2

I'm using this code:-

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $infoDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();

        foreach ($infoDataObject as $itemId => $itemInfo) {

           $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
           $product = $item->getProduct();

         }
          echo "<pre>"; print_r($product); echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tryp to change `$infoDataObject` to the following:

```
$infoDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo()->toArray();
```

Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/515b0b8e9603bdbf85dd92fb4f226c94c8b6d834/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Observer/CartUpdateBefore.php

Comment: Thanks that worked, I want to add option on click of update cart items button. But not able to accmplish that. below is the code in the same file
foreach ($infoDataObject as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
 $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
 $product = $item->getProduct();
 $additionalOptions = array(array('code'  => 'my_code','label' => 'This text is displayed through additional options2','value' => 'ID is '));
 $product->addOption(array('code'  => 'additional_options','value' => serialize($additionalOptions)));
}

Comment: What options (or tasks) you want to add?

Comment: As i mentioned in the code above i have taken an array named $additionaloptions that options as custom options of the product.

Comment: I recommend you to ask another question, out of the scope already.

Comment: ok will post that now.

Comment: Here is the link to the Question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187329/magento-2-1-add-additional-options-or-custom-options-in-the-product-on-click-o

Comment: Have you seen the above posted question?

Comment: Yes I know that, reading

Answer (score 2):

In your `observer`,

```
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo()->toArray();

        foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
            $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
            print_r($item->getProduct()->getData());
            exit;
        },
```

`Magento` itself using this event, you can see the reference from here

`Magento\Wishlist\Observer\CartUpdateBefore` class.

Only missing part from your code is

```
    $data = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo()->toArray();
```

Comment: Your answer is just the same as mine, nothing new.

Comment: Yes, you are too fast :) @PYYick

Comment: Thanks Keyur, I have loaded the product but after this i want to add custom options in to the product. Here is the link to the Question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187329/magento-2-1-add-additional-options-or-custom-options-in-the-product-on-click-o