# Magento 2 - Add additional options or custom options in the product on click of 'Update cart' button on cart page

Tags: magento2

This is Observer file:-

```
<?php
namespace Neologix\Bopis\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,CheckoutSession  $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $infoDataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo()->toArray();
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();

        foreach ($infoDataObject as $itemId => $itemInfo) {

           $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
           $product = $item->getProduct();
           **// able to load product but after this code is not working for adding options to the product**
           $additionalOptions = array(
                array(
                    'code'  => 'my_code',
                    'label' => 'This text is displayed through additional options2',
                    'value' => 'ID is '
                )
            );
             $product->addOption(
                array(
                     'code'  => 'additional_options',
                     'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any examples that what will the page look like?

Comment: Here is the link to screen shot what i am talking about.
Link :- http://prntscr.com/g3b90a

Comment: If the product type is configurable, the option should show automatically. You may check any layouts that removed this class, or just hidden by CSS.

Comment: You can check this in demo store: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/